# Binding monads into composites (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, bind, monads, composite

Good day folks. I'm seeking some clarifications on monads please and using bind (while going into a composite `.`) please.

So for this example:

```
--Monadic parts:
readFile :: String -> IO File
putStr :: String -> IO()
-- Non monadic parts
toMatrix :: String -> CustomMatrix
toString :: CustomMatrix -> String
```

Essentially I'm lazily reading a file (`readFile`) then producing a custom matrix, converting the matrix to a string output. Then returning.

```
fileReading :: String -> IO
fileReading file = putStr(toString . toMatrix . readFile file)
```

This is when I start creating a mess by using bind `>>=` to go from `readFile file`. Is there a way I can continue to use composites `.` and bind and compose without making an unreadable mess (not really my aim).

As always, any help is gratefully received. Thanks folks.

Comment: Variable and function names cannot start with a digit, so I am renaming `2Matrix` and `2String` in your question.

Comment: Apologies. I was making my function names shorter without thinking.

Comment: The analogy of `(.)` for functions of type `a -> m b` for some monad `m` is called `(<=<)` (from `Control.Monad`) and is called Kleisli Composition.  You can mix it with `.` depending on the types of what you are composing. E.g. `fileReading = putStr . toString . toMatrix <=< readFile`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get away without using *some* monadic function (like `>>=`) in this example. You can't use normal function composition with IO values if you actually want to end up doing some IO.

Happily, you can still write the code fairly readably:

```
fileReading file = readFile file >>= putStr . toString . toMatrix
```

This works because the two `.` operations combine two non-IO functions with a final IO function. At that point, you have two IO values: an `IO String` and a `String -> IO ()` function (the entire `putStr . toString . toMatrix` expression has that type). This is exactly what `>>=` takes, so you're all set.

If you want the code to have the same order as above, you can use the backwards bind operator:

```
fileReading file = putStr . toString . toMatrix =<< readFile file
```

Some people find this version more readable because all of the code "flows" in the same direction.